# Check for invalid input in a menu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am making a script where the user selects a number 1-5 and it will loop until the user enters 5. I don't want to use the exit command. I wanted to check to make sure the user doesn't enter anything but 1-5 and if they do display invalid input.

any help would be appreciated

```
#!/bin/bash
  PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("1.Move empty files" "2.Check file size" "3.Which files is newer" "4.File check rwx" select opt in "${options[@]}")


 while($opt != 5); do
   case $opt in

        "Option 1")
          echo "you chose choice 1"
          ;;
        "Option 2")
          echo "you chose choice 2"
          ;;

        "Option 3")


     echo "you chose choice 3"
    ;;
 "Option 4")
  echo "you chose choice 3"
               ;;
          "Option 5")
           break
           ;;
   ) echo invalid input;;
```

Comment: Setting `PS3` is meaningless if you aren't using a `select` statement, which is what you appear to want in place of the `while` loop.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `case` is overkill here, `opt` will be empty if the selection was invalid. You also don't need the `while` since `select` is already a loop.

Comment: You say both "loop until the user enters 5" and "make sure the user doesn't enter anything but 1-5"--so which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem confused. I don't even know where to begin correcting whatever misconceptions you have about how this works

In your original code the way you set `options` is unlikely to do anything useful.

```
options=("1.Move empty files" "2.Check file size" "3.Which files is newer" "4.File check rwx" select opt in "${options[@]}"
printf '%s\n' "${options[@]}"
```

This will emit

```
1.Move empty files
2.Check file size
3.Which files is newer
4.File check rwx
select
opt
in
```

The `select` command will not have been executed.

Here's something that does what you seem to want.

```
options=(
    'Move empty files'
    'Check file size'
    'Which file is newer'
    'File check rwx'
)

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
select opt in "${options[@]}" ; do
    [[ -n $opt ]] && break || {
        echo "invalid input"
    }
done
echo "user chose '$opt'"
```

You could go with a `while` and `case` solution and get nearly the same results e.g.:

```
options=(
    'Move empty files'
    'Check file size'
    'Which file is newer'
    'File check rwx'
)

for (( i=0 ; i < ${#options[@]} ; i++ )) ; do
    printf '%d) %s\n' $((i+1)) "${options[$i]}"
done
while true ; do
    read -p 'Please enter your choice: ' opt
    case "$opt" in
        [1-5])
            opt="${options[$opt]}"
            break
        ;;
        *)
            echo "invalid input"
        ;;
    esac
done

echo "user chose '$opt'"
```

But you don't need **both** and, as you can see, using `select` is much simpler.